# Application of calculus to find the minimum cost

Tags: calculus

A frame of a shelter is made of rods of two different lengths:

- $x$ metres for top and bottom edges
- $y$ metres for each sloping edge

The frame is to be covered by a rectangular sheet of material.

Total area of sheet is $24m^2$.

[image]

1. Show the total length, $L$ metres of the rods used in a shelter is given by:
   $L = 3x + {\frac{48}x}$
2. To minimise costs, the total length of rods used in a frame must be as small as possible .  Calculate the minimum cost of a frame.

For part 1, I would say that

Area = $2xy = 24$

$y = \frac{12}x$

The frame is made up of $3x$ rods for top and bottom and $4y$ for the side rods.

$L = 3x + 4(\frac{12}x)$

$L = 3x + \frac{48}x$

For part 2, stationary points occur when $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

So I should take the derivative of $f(x) = 3x + \frac{48}x$

Which is $3 - 48x^{-2}$

I'm not sure if this is right or how to proceed from here.

Comment: So far so good. Now just set the derivative equal to $0$ and solve for x. Use x to get y and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the derivative equal to zero now.

$$3 - \frac{48}{x^2} = 0$$
$$\therefore \frac{3x^2 - 48}{x^2} = 0$$
Assuming that $x \neq 0$,
$$ 3x^2 - 48 = 0 $$
$$\therefore x^2 = 16$$
$$\therefore x = 4$$

and subsequently,
$$ y = \frac{12}{x} $$
$$ \therefore y = 3 $$

Hence the minimum total length of frame is,
$$ L_{min} = 3x + \frac{48}{x} $$
$$ L_{min} = 24 $$

Hence the minimum cost of the frame is now,
$$Cost_{min} = L_{min}*(cost \hspace{4pt} per \hspace{4pt} metre)$$
Or based on the area the cost can be calculated as,
$$ Cost_{min} = 24 * (cost \hspace{4pt} per \hspace{4pt} metre^2)$$

Comment: how does $$3 - \frac{48}{x^2} = 0$$ become 
$$ x^2 = 16$$

Comment: @dagda1 : check my updated answer.

Comment: this is very helpful